# How to calculate Quarterly difference and add missing Quarterly with count in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am having a data frame like this I have to get missing Quarterly value and count between them
Same with Quarterly Missing count and fill  the data frame is

```
year    Data    Id
    2019Q4   57170   A
    2019Q3   55150   A
    2019Q2   51109   A 
    2019Q1   51109   A
    2018Q1   57170   B
    2018Q4   55150   B
    2017Q4   51109   C
    2017Q2   51109   C
    2017Q1   51109   C
```

Id Start year end-year count

```
  B  2018Q2    2018Q3        2
  B  2017Q3    2018Q3        1
```

How can I achieve this using python panda

Comment: Have you tried anything ? Please provide the code that you have tried before posting here.

Comment: I am not getting any idea to implement this.so for that i posted

Comment: I am getting an error like this     df1 = (y.set_index('year').groupby('Id')['Id'].apply(lambda x: x.reindex(np.arange(x.index.min(), x.index.max() + 1))).reset_index(name='val',errors='coerce'))
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
#changed data for more general solution - multiple missing years per groups
print (df)
   year   Data Id
0  2015  57170  A
1  2016  55150  A
2  2019  51109  A
3  2023  51109  A
4  2000  47740  B
5  2002  44563  B
6  2003  43643  C
7  2004  42050  C
8  2007  37312  C
```

---

```
#add missing values for no years by reindex
df1 = (df.set_index('year')
       .groupby('Id')['Id']
       .apply(lambda x: x.reindex(np.arange(x.index.min(), x.index.max() + 1)))
       .reset_index(name='val'))
print (df1)
   Id  year  val
0   A  2015    A
1   A  2016    A
2   A  2017  NaN
3   A  2018  NaN
4   A  2019    A
5   A  2020  NaN
6   A  2021  NaN
7   A  2022  NaN
8   A  2023    A
9   B  2000    B
10  B  2001  NaN
11  B  2002    B
12  C  2003    C
13  C  2004    C
14  C  2005  NaN
15  C  2006  NaN
16  C  2007    C
```

---

```
#boolean mask for check no NaNs to variable for reuse
m = df1['val'].notnull().rename('g')
#create index by cumulative sum for unique groups for consecutive NaNs
df1.index = m.cumsum()

#filter only NaNs row and aggregate first, last and count.
df2 = (df1[~m.values].groupby(['Id', 'g'])['year']
                     .agg(['first','last','size'])
                     .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
                     .reset_index())
print (df2)
  Id  first  last  size
0  A   2017  2018     2
1  A   2020  2022     3
2  B   2001  2001     1
3  C   2005  2006     2
```

EDIT:

```
#convert to datetimes
df['year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['year'], format='%Y%m')
#resample by start of months with asfreq
df1 = df.set_index('year').groupby('Id')['Id'].resample('MS').asfreq().rename('val').reset_index()
print (df1)
   Id       year  val
0   A 2015-05-01    A
1   A 2015-06-01  NaN
2   A 2015-07-01    A
3   A 2015-08-01  NaN
4   A 2015-09-01    A
5   B 2000-01-01    B
6   B 2000-02-01  NaN
7   B 2000-03-01    B
8   C 2003-01-01    C
9   C 2003-02-01    C
10  C 2003-03-01  NaN
11  C 2003-04-01  NaN
12  C 2003-05-01    C
```

---

```
m = df1['val'].notnull().rename('g')
#create index by cumulative sum for unique groups for consecutive NaNs
df1.index = m.cumsum()

#filter only NaNs row and aggregate first, last and count.
df2 = (df1[~m.values].groupby(['Id', 'g'])['year']
                     .agg(['first','last','size'])
                     .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
                     .reset_index())
print (df2)
  Id      first       last  size
0  A 2015-06-01 2015-06-01     1
1  A 2015-08-01 2015-08-01     1
2  B 2000-02-01 2000-02-01     1
3  C 2003-03-01 2003-04-01     2
```

Comment: I am getting an error like this df1 = (y.set_index('year').groupby('Id')['Id'].apply(lambda x: x.reindex(np.arange(x.index.min(), x.index.max() + 1))).reset_index(name='val',errors='coerce')) TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found

Comment: @raam - I think need convert `year` column to integer as first step by `df['year'] = df['year'].astype(int)`

Comment: can i get month difference and count like year with same logic year 201505 201502  output is like 201506 201507 2

Comment: @raam - Can you modify data in question?

Comment: @ jezrael  Modified data in question

Comment: @ jezrael can you implement for missing days and missing weeks i updated the question can you check it.and give me solution.

Comment: @raam need ``df['year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['year'], format='%Y%m%d')
df1 = df.set_index('year').groupby('Id')['Id'].resample('d').asfreq().rename('val').reset_index()``

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176099/discussion-between-raam-and-jezrael).

Comment: @ jezrael i have improved the question with week missing and quarter missing how can i achieve this one.Can you do it.

Comment: @raam - Question is completely changed, please rather create new question, because now this answer not working with question data. Thanks.

Comment: @raam - So I suggest create new question with actual content of this question and then rollback to 3 [link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51358247/revisions) - then question will match with answer. Thanks.

Comment: @ jezrael I have asked new question and this is the question How to calculate weeks difference and add missing Weeks with count in python pandas

Comment: @ jezrael I have given Quarterly data can you give me the solution

Comment: @raam - OK, so problem is not match question with answer, is problem create new question?

Comment: @raam - My idea is not delete question/answer but create new one for each similar, but not same question/answer.

Comment: @ jezrael I have given new question for  Quarterly data can you give me the solution

Comment: can pass the range of years 2014 to 2024 for id A and find the missing years for id A