# how to compare or merge two data frames using python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

How do I compare/merge two data frames based on the start and data columns and get the missing gaps with the count.

Dataframe 1

```
id start 
1  2009
1  2010
1  2011
1  2012
2  2010
2  2011
2  2012
2  2013
2  2014
```

Data frame 2

```
id data
1   2010
1   2012
2   2010
2   2011
2   2012
```

Expected Output:

```
id first last size
1  2009   2009 1
1  2011   2011 1
2  2013   2014 2
```

How may I achieve this.

Comment: what attempt have you made so far?

Comment: I was new to pandas so i have created both data frames.from then i dont know what to do.

Comment: can you explain how you are getting your expected output?

Comment: @Chris Data frame 1 contains all the year from start to end for a each id.dataframe2 is the data contains for each id.Now we have find the missing year in dataframe 2 and print the missing the years in dataframe 2 for that id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with `indicator=True` and outer join first:

```
df11 = df1.rename(columns={'start':'data'})
df = df2.merge(df11, how='outer', indicator=True, on=['id','data']).sort_values(['id','data'])
print (df)
   id  data      _merge
5   1  2009  right_only
0   1  2010        both
6   1  2011  right_only
1   1  2012        both
2   2  2010        both
3   2  2011        both
4   2  2012        both
7   2  2013  right_only
8   2  2014  right_only
```

And then use [old solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51358490/2901002) - only change condition:

```
#boolean mask for check no right_only to variable for reuse
m = (df['_merge'] != 'right_only').rename('g')
#create index by cumulative sum for unique groups for consecutive NaNs
df.index = m.cumsum()
print (df)
   id  data      _merge
g                      
0   1  2009  right_only
1   1  2010        both
1   1  2011  right_only
2   1  2012        both
3   2  2010        both
4   2  2011        both
5   2  2012        both
5   2  2013  right_only
5   2  2014  right_only
```

---

```
#filter only NaNs row and aggregate first, last and count.
df2 = (df[~m.values].groupby(['id', 'g'])['data']
                     .agg(['first','last','size'])
                     .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
                     .reset_index())
print (df2)
   id  first  last  size
0   1   2009  2009     1
1   1   2011  2011     1
2   2   2013  2014     2
```

Comment: in df I am having another column say x how can I get when I am using groupby(['id','g'])['data'].I am trying like this  groupby(['id','g','x'])['data'].I am getting error on doing this.

Comment: @raam - Do you think `df.groupby(['id','g'])['data'].max()` ?

Comment: No..what I am saying is I have to get all the columns in df.on doing this step df2 = (df[~m.values].groupby(['id', 'g'])['data']
                     .agg(['first','last','size'])
                     .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
                     .reset_index())  I am getting only I'd,first,last,size.

Comment: Yes, try remove `.reset_index(level=1, drop=True)`

Comment: I have to get all the columns which are in df

Comment: If I remove .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)  I am getting g column as index extra to I'd first last size but I am not getting x column.

Comment: @raam - Sorry, if remove `.reset_index(level=1, drop=True)` it not get `x` column ?

Comment: Before grouping:  Index([u'data', u'end', u'f', u'id', u'start',u'_merge'], dtype='object') After grouping:
Index([u'id', u'g', u'first', u'last', u'size'], dtype='object') I need f column after grouping also.

Comment: @raam - i understand now. Problem is need replace `['data'].agg(['first','last','size'])` to `.agg({'data':['first','last','size'], 'f':'first'})` - for column `f` use some aggregate funcion, e.g. first

Comment: No I am not am able to get it.

Comment: It is creating multi index.i have different question can I ask

Comment: No necessary, use `df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51969476/how-to-compare-two-dataframes-on-a-column-and-replace-with-other-column-value

Comment: @raam - Thank you for link, unfortunately i was offline yesterday. But solution with `map` is really good ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178662/discussion-between-raam-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question for you yesterday. I dont know where you are getting the first and last columns but here is a way to find the missing years based on the example above:

```
df1_year = pd.DataFrame(df1.groupby('id')['start'].apply(list))
df2_year = pd.DataFrame(df2.groupby('id')['data'].apply(list))
dfs = [df1_year,df2_year]
df_final = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on='id'), dfs)
df_final.reset_index(inplace=True)

def noMatch(a, b):
    return [x for x in a if x not in b]

df3 = []
for i in range(0, len(df_final)):
    df3.append(noMatch(df_final['start'][i],df_final['data'][i]))

missing_year = pd.DataFrame(df3)
missing_year['missingYear'] = missing_year.values.tolist()
df_concat = pd.concat([df_final, missing_year], axis=1)
df_concat = df_concat[['id','missingYear']]
df4 = []
for i in range(0,len(df_concat)):
    df4.append(df_concat.applymap(lambda x: x[i] if isinstance(x, list) else x))
df_final1 = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on='id'), df4)
pd.concat([df_final1[['id','missingYear_x']], df_final1[['id','missingYear_y']].rename(columns={'missingYear_y':'missingYear_x'})]).rename(columns={'missingYear_x':'missingYear'}).sort_index()

    id  missingYear
0   1   2009
0   1   2011
1   2   2013
1   2   2014
```

to add it to df2 per your comment just append data

Comment: The first and last columns are missing years..missing year is 2013 and 2014 for Id 2 first is 2013 and last 2014 and that  size is 2...for id 1 their is no consecutive missing years for that first is 2009 and last is 2009 size is 1