# How to compare two Dataframes on a column and replace with other column value

Tags: python, pandas

I have two input dataframes, df1 and df2:

```
id      first       last  size
  A 1978-01-01 1979-01-01     2
  B 2000-01-01 2000-01-01     1
  C 1998-01-01 2000-01-01     3
  D 1998-01-01 1998-01-01     1
  E 1999-01-01 2000-01-01     2

  id  token       
  A     ZA.00 
  B     As.11
  C     SD.34
```

My desired output:

```
id          first       last        size
  ZA.00     1978-01-01 1979-01-01     2
  As.11     2000-01-01 2000-01-01     1
  SD.34     1998-01-01 2000-01-01     3
  D         1998-01-01 1998-01-01     1
  E         1999-01-01 2000-01-01     2
```

If `df2['id']` matches `df1['id']` then replace `df1['id']` with `df2['token']`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Use `map` and `fillna`:

```
df1['id'] = df1['id'].map(df2.set_index('id')['token']).fillna(df1['id'])
df1
```

Output:

```
      id       first        last  size
0  ZA.00  1978-01-01  1979-01-01     2
1  As.11  2000-01-01  2000-01-01     1
2  SD.34  1998-01-01  2000-01-01     3
3      D  1998-01-01  1998-01-01     1
4      E  1999-01-01  2000-01-01     2
```

You can use `map` with a series as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`Merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas-dataframe-merge) and [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
df = df1.merge(df2,how='outer')
df['id'] = df['token'].combine_first(df['id'] )
df.drop('token',inplace=True,axis=1)
```

Another way is to use [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html#pandas-series-replace) with dictionary of `df2.values`, here the df1 dataframe changes.:

```
df1.id.replace(dict(df2.values),inplace=True)
```

---

```
        id  first   last    size
    0   ZA.00   1978-01-01  1979-01-01  2
    1   As.11   2000-01-01  2000-01-01  1
    2   SD.34   1998-01-01  2000-01-01  3
    3   D   1998-01-01  1998-01-01  1
    4   E   1999-01-01  2000-01-01  2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not wish to merge your DataFrame, you could use apply function to solve this. Change your small DataFrame to dictionary and map it to the other DataFrame.

```
from io import StringIO #used to get string to df

import pandas as pd

id_ =list('ABC')
token = 'ZA.00 As.11 SD.34'.split()
dt = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(id_,token)),columns=['id','token'])

a ='''
id first last size
A 1978-01-01 1979-01-01 2
B 2000-01-01 2000-01-01 1
C 1998-01-01 2000-01-01 3
D 1998-01-01 1998-01-01 1
E 1999-01-01 2000-01-01 2
'''

df =pd.read_csv(StringIO(a), sep=' ')

# This last two lines are all you need
mp= {x:y for x,y in zip(dt.id.tolist(),dt.token.tolist())}

df.id.apply(lambda x: mp[x] if x in mp.keys() else x)
```